# maximize intra-group correlation while minimizing inter-group correlation

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, data-science

I am trying to figure out if there's a way to find a way to sort objects that maximises the intra-group correlation and minimize inter-group correlation.

For example, let there be a data frame DF containing 12 columns s1 to s12, each with 100 observations. Let's say each represents return on stock.

I want to find a way to sort this data into 3 groups of 4 variables which would maximize intra-group correlation and minimize inter-group correlation.
Assuming the Pearson method works well,

```
df_cor <- cor(df)
```

This will give a 12x12 correlation matrix.

My intuition is by using this correlation matrix, I should make a code to select only the unique pairs which would give the biggest sum of correlation coefficients, but I am kind of lost.

Can any of you give hints about how to do this?

My real data has 2000 columns each with 3000 observations, and I have to separate them into 10 groups.

I'm doing it with R, but I'm okay with doing it with python too.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

A while back I wrote a function [(func_correlation)](https://github.com/mlampros/FeatureSelection/blob/master/R/correlation_of_multiple_predictors.R) which takes a matrix or data frame (of predictors) and returns highly correlated pairs taking into consideration a number of parameters. Hopefully is what you actually ask.

Example data,

```
lst_s = list()

set.seed(1) 
for (i in 1:12) {

  nam = paste0("s_", i)

  lst_s[[nam]] = runif(100)
}

s_matr = do.call(cbind, lst_s)
```

By using [*devtools::install_github('mlampros/FeatureSelection')*](https://github.com/mlampros/FeatureSelection) you can install the package and then run ,

```
dat = FeatureSelection::func_correlation(s_matr, target = NULL, correlation_thresh = 0.05, use_obs = "everything", correlation_method = "pearson")

# here the *correlation_thresh* is low because I use random data, adjust it to your needs
```

It returns a list (*out_list*) and a data frame (*out_df*). The list shows correlations of *individual* predictors above the *correlation_thresh*,

```
$out_list
$out_list[[1]]
           s_1
s_3 0.14450632
s_6 0.10891246
s_7 0.13232308
s_8 0.07818346
s_9 0.06381170

$out_list[[2]]
           s_2
s_10 0.1380704
s_11 0.1737746

.........
```

whereas the data frame shows all pairs of predictors above the *correlation_thresh*,

```
$out_df
   predictor1 predictor2       prob
1         s_3        s_1 0.14450632
2         s_6        s_1 0.10891246
3         s_7        s_1 0.13232308
4         s_8        s_1 0.07818346
5         s_9        s_1 0.06381170
6        s_10        s_2 0.13807039
7        s_11        s_2 0.17377459
8         s_4        s_3 0.10395950
9         s_6        s_3 0.21541706

...............
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was wondering what the difference with your function and melting the correlation matrix(and sorting in descending order of correlation) is?

Comment: @TaeyoungAhn, I assume my answer was not what you actually expect to have as output.